# Excluding file while compressing in SSIS

Tags: ssis, zip

Through a SSIS task,I was trying to exclude one of three files in a location to being compressed,But failed

While,It successfully compressed all files. I am using PKZIP utility.

```
"-add " + @[User::Outbound_Directory] + "Test"+  @DataMonth +  ".zip  \"" +  @[User::Outbound_Directory] + "*.txt\""
```

This command is working for all files

I tried -excl command and mentioned the specific file name but failed.

```
"-add " + " -excl = r.txt" + @[User::Outbound_Directory] + "Test"+  @DataMonth +  ".zip  \"" +  @[User::Outbound_Directory] + "*.txt\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a space after `r.txt` and before the double quote that follows it:

```
"-add " + " -excl = r.txt " + ...
```